# Sorting parent div by content in child div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to sort the elements inside conainer using jquery, I have used this fiddle as a reference http://jsfiddle.net/tc5dc/. I dont know what is possibly wrong ??

Also if there is any other way i can get this done in a more simple and DRY way.

```
                    <div class="container"><!--Container-->
                    <div class="element"><!--Single element-->
                        <div class="child1">                                
                        </div>
                        <div class="child2">
                            <div class="stats right">
                                <div class="stat">
                                    <h1 class="inv">0</h1>
                                    <h4 id ="mInv"class="sort" >Inv</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="stat">
                                    <h1 class="con">14</h1>
                                    <h4 id="mCon" class="sort" >Con</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="stat">
                                    <h1 class="ts">66</h1>
                                    <h4 id="mTs" class="sort" >TS</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="element"><!--Single element-->
                        <div class="child1">                                
                        </div>
                        <div class="child2">
                            <div class="stats right">
                                <div class="stat">
                                    <h1 class="inv">10</h1>
                                    <h4 id ="mInv"class="sort" >Inv</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="stat">
                                    <h1 class="con">12</h1>
                                    <h4 id="mCon" class="sort" >Con</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="stat">
                                    <h1 class="ts">90</h1>
                                    <h4 id="mTs" class="sort" >TS</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="element"><!--Single element-->
                        <div class="child1">                                
                        </div>
                        <div class="child2">
                            <div class="stats right">
                                <div class="stat">
                                    <h1 class="inv">17</h1>
                                    <h4 id ="mInv"class="sort" >Inv</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="stat">
                                    <h1 class="con">81</h1>
                                    <h4 id="mCon" class="sort" >Con</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="stat">
                                    <h1 class="ts">124</h1>
                                    <h4 id="mTs" class="sort" >TS</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**JS**

```
function sortUsingNestedText(parent, childSelector, keySelector) {
var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
    var vA = $(keySelector, a).text();
    var vB = $(keySelector, b).text();
    return (vA < vB) ? -1 : (vA > vB) ? 1 : 0;
});
parent.append(items);
}

/* setup sort attributes */
$('#mInv').data("sortKey", "h1.inv");
$('#mCon').data("sortKey", "h1.con");
$('#mTs').data("sortKey", "h1.ts");


/* sort on button click */
$("h4.sort").click(function() {
sortUsingNestedText($('#sortThis'), "div", $(this).data("sortKey"));
```

Comment: h4.sort has no child elements that I can see in your code, and you don't have the ID 'sortThis' in your html, not sure what you hope to accomplish

Comment: I am trying to sort <div class="element"></div><!--Single element-->, based on value of <h1></h1>.

Comment: There is no element in your code with an id of "sortThis"...did you leave something out?

Comment: @Snowburnt http://jsfiddle.net/tc5dc/ see this fiddle

Comment: @SpaceTruck the fiddle that you reference just says to find a dom element by ID and sort its children elements but you don't have that element or its structure in your code you'll need to rewrite the jquery

Comment: @Culyx Can you suggest any alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to achieve it, I'm not sure what all the page has in terms of css, etc. The way you have the sort bound to the h4 tag makes it look like you have a list of 3 items that you sort by clicking one of the items?

Comment: @SpaceTruck added a fiddle to my answer that I worked up to show you another possible solution, uses data in nested children so it's a bit closer to what you're doing, still not perfect but it should get you started

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems you'll have immediately is that with trying to sort `.element` by children is that the `H1` tags are not children of `.element`

```
<div class="element"><!--Single element-->
                    <div class="child1">                                
                    </div>
                    <div class="child2">
                        <div class="stats right">
                            <div class="stat">
                                <h1></h1>
                                <h4></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="stat">
                                <h1></h1>
                                <h4></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="stat">
                                <h1></h1>
                                <h4></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Looking at this element `.child1` has no children, `.child2` has 1 child and that is `.stats` the div with 2 classes `.stats and .right` has 3 children divs and those divs each have child `h1` and `h4` tags

```
var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b)
```

only attempts to sort 1 layer down

If you want to keep all the nesting one simple way to fix it would be to use `.find` instead of `.children`

EDIT: Fiddle that shows another way of doing sort, this time with data nested inside the children of the children you're trying to sort; probably not that great but it works and gives you an idea of possible implementations (i.e. there is room for improvement there) http://jsfiddle.net/tc5dc/702/

Fiddle code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="element">
    <div class="stat">
         <h1 class="inv">0</h1>
         <h4 id="mInv" class="sort">Inv</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="stat">
         <h1 class="ts">66</h1>
         <h4 id="mTs" class="sort">TS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="stat">
         <h1 class="con">14</h1>
         <h4 id="mCon" class="sort">Con</h4>
    </div>
</div>

$("div.stat").click(function () {
        var list = $(".element").children("div");
        list.sort(sortDesc);
        $(".container").html("");
        $(".container").append(list);
    });

    function sortDesc(a, b) {
        var test1 = jQuery(a);
        var test2 = jQuery(b);
        return test1.find("h1").text() > test2.find("h1").text();
    }
```